# React Js Hooks / props.Children on chatbot

Tags: reactjs

Hello I had the following logic to make a simple chat bot, but for some reason I am not able to display the messages:

```
const ChatBot = () => {
  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <ChatMessage bot={true}>Hi.</ChatMessage>
      <ChatMessage bot={false}>Hello.</ChatMessage>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};
```

and this is my chatbot:

```
function ChatMessage(props) {
  return (
    <Styled.ChatMessage bot={props.bot}>{props.children}</Styled.ChatMessage>
  );
}

ChatMessage.defaultProps = {
  bot: false,
};

const Chat = props => {
  console.log(props.children);
  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <Styled.ChatHeader />
      <Styled.ChatLog>{props.children}</Styled.ChatLog>
      <Styled.ChatInput>
        <textarea placeholder="aaaaa ..." rows={4} />
        <button>Send</button>
      </Styled.ChatInput>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};
```

I'm really not able to identify what I did wrong
and I don't know if I did it in the best way or with the best logic
I have a div made with styled comp
which will be where the messages will be displayed according to the prop bot
and I will have the message, but for some reason I am not able to display the message.
example on:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-torvalds-fyi77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are missing `export default ChatBot` in your `chatbot/index.js` file.
[image]

Comment: u can help me with this bro? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992794/react-js-chat-bot-with-hooks

Answer (score 0):

You aren't exporting `ChatBot` from `src/chatbot/index.js`, you are actually exporting `Chat`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Chat, ChatMessage } from "./chat";
const ChatBot = () => {
  return (
    <Chat>
      <ChatMessage bot={true}>Hi.</ChatMessage>
      <ChatMessage bot={false}>Hello.</ChatMessage>
    </Chat>
  );
};

//export default Chat; // You're just exporting what you imported
export default ChatBot; // This is correct
```

If you change that it should work. See the example below.  You will need to run the snippet in fullscreen since the messages will appear off-screen due to your styling.

```js
const {useState, useEffect, Fragment} = React;
const {css} = styled;

const messageBot = css`
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
`;
const messageClient = css`
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: #ffffff;
`;
const ChatBox = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 22em;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: red;
`;
const ChatLog = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1 100%;
  background: blue;
`;

const ChatMessage = styled.div`
  margin: 1ex;
  padding: 1ex;
  border-radius: 2px;
  ${props => (props.bot ? messageBot : messageClient)}
`;

const ChatInput = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  padding: 1ex;
  max-height: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  flex: none;
  & > textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 1 1;
    resize: none;
  }
`;

const ChatHeader = styled.div`
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  flex: none;
  background: green;
  height: 30px;
`;

const Styled = {
  ChatBox,
  ChatLog,
  ChatHeader,
  ChatInput,
  ChatMessage
};


function ChatMessageCmp(props) {
  return (
    <Styled.ChatMessage bot={props.bot}>{props.children}</Styled.ChatMessage>
  );
}

ChatMessageCmp.defaultProps = {
  bot: false
};

const Chat = props => {
  console.log(props.children);
  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <Styled.ChatHeader />
      <Styled.ChatLog>{props.children}</Styled.ChatLog>
      <Styled.ChatInput>
        <textarea placeholder="aaaaa ..." rows={4} />
        <button>Send</button>
      </Styled.ChatInput>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};

const ChatBot = () => {
  return (
    <Chat>
      <ChatMessageCmp bot={true}>Hi.</ChatMessageCmp>
      <ChatMessageCmp bot={false}>Hello.</ChatMessageCmp>
    </Chat>
  );
};

function App() {
  return <ChatBot />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components@4.4.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```