# ReactJS / Chatbot with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatbot

I have a static chatbot where I can display the messages through this:

> `<ChatMessage bot={true}>Hi.</ChatMessage>`

like this img:

[image]

```
const ChatBot = () => {
  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <ChatMessage bot={true}>Hi.</ChatMessage>
      <ChatMessage bot={false}>Hello.</ChatMessage>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};
```

and this is my chatbot:

```
function ChatMessage(props) {
  return (
    <Styled.ChatMessage bot={props.bot}>{props.children}</Styled.ChatMessage>
  );
}

ChatMessage.defaultProps = {
  bot: false,
};

const Chat = props => {
  console.log(props.children);
  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <Styled.ChatHeader />
      <Styled.ChatLog>{props.children}</Styled.ChatLog>
      <Styled.ChatInput>
        <textarea placeholder="aaaaa ..." rows={4} />
        <button>Send</button>
      </Styled.ChatInput>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};
```

But I would like to know how I could make it dynamic to display a message accordingly with what is typed in the text area and as a result call some function to check what was typed as a string and return a response. But I don't know how to resolve this situation. Basically I need to display a message typed by a user in the chat and send that message to my back-end (or some function of the front-end), then that function will send me a response.

For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-torvalds-fyi77

Answer (score 0):

```
<Chat>
  <ChatMessage bot={true}>Hi.</ChatMessage>
  <ChatMessage bot={false}>Hello.</ChatMessage>
</Chat>
```

First of all, the above code should be changed to use a `prop` instead of hard-coding, like this:

```
const ChatBot = ({ messages }) => {
  return (
    <Chat>
      {messages.map(message => <ChatMessage bot={message.fromBot}>{message.text}</ChatMessage>)}
    </Chat>
  );
};
```

Second, in your parent, you should `connect` your `messages` state to redux (or simply load messages in the component and save it in `messages` state), and pass it down as a prop to the above component.

Finally, once you submit a new message, you can call a `sendMessage` prop passed from the parent, which calls the API to send message. Also, you need to remember to update the current list of messages upon successfully sending it to the server, so your local state is up-to-date.

Comment: oops i liked this solution could you give me an example of how i would do it with dad?

basically a button and save the messages with useState at the moment, but how would I send it to my component chat?

Comment: send it as a prop like this: <ChatBot messages={this.state.messages} />

Comment: I couldn't imagine how to do this using chat.js and index.js and hooks
I was a little confused. Could you set an example with your father?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you've to keep your messages array in a state variable and add your messages dynamically on press of a button. You can do something like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  const handleClick = () => {
    setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, text]);
    setText('')
  }

  return (
    <>
      <textarea onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}>{text}</textarea>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

It's only an example, you can map it on your use case.

Comment: hello friend thank you
do you think the best option would be to use redux to store these messages? since I will send them to the backend and will I receive as a response?

Comment: I understood this part, but I'm not sure how I'm going to do this part:

const ChatBot = () => {
  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <ChatMessage bot = {true}> Hi. </ChatMessage>
      <ChatMessage bot = {false}> Hello. </ChatMessage>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work very well the text didn't appear in my component log